# Running a Java application on a webpage

Tags: java, html

I have written a Java application that I would like to run inside of a web page. How do I do this?

Code is below:

```
class Permutations {
    static long factorial(int num){
            long factorial = 1;
            for (int forBlockvar = num; forBlockvar > 1; forBlockvar--) {
                    factorial = factorial * forBlockvar;
            }
            return factorial;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
            long FactNmR;
            int n = 10;
            int num = n;
            int r = 4;
            int nMr = n - r;
            long FactN = factorial(num);
            if (nMr <= 1){
                    FactNmR = 1;
            }
            else  {
                    num = nMr;
                    FactNmR = factorial(num);
            }
            long permutations = FactN;
            permutations = permutations / FactNmR;
            System.out.println(permutations);
   }
}
```

Comment: Good background info, but please try to elaborate with anything else you may know.  Hard for us to help when all we know is that you have an application and a website.

Comment: Could you flesh out exactly what you mean? What is the "running code," and how do you envision it "on a website?"

Comment: So, you want to port your Java (standalone) application onto a website. Is it an all command-line application?

Comment: Otay, I have a friend who does CSS by hand, and she will help me with the basics, but we don't know the HTML stuff.

Comment: Knowing that it's a eighth grader asking for some help with homework I would never downvote this. I think that would be discouragement.

Comment: It will have swing, but that is in the works.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow, - Are you looking to make an [applet](http://java.sun.com/applets/jdk/1.4/demo/applets/ArcTest/example1.html) ?

Comment: I want to have it so there is a square block on a website that has my java application, and visitors will be able to use it.

Comment: If it is Swing, you can think of [JNLP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start) and provide a link to your app on the HTML. Take a look at [Oracle's Official Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/deploying.html)

Comment: Thank you for the support, @gurung.  I am not exactly sure whether to make it an applet or not, this is my first fairly large project in java.

Comment: @CodeAdmiral you are looking to make an applet. Pleas see my link above. Oracle/Sun has a bunch of tutorials about applets. Start [here](http://java.sun.com/applets/)

Comment: Oh, otay @adarshr.  I kind of understand what you are saying.  But what exactly is the difference between an applet and an application?

Comment: @CodeAdmiral an applet is like an embedded Java application that runs withn a Java-enabled browser. With JNLP, you just link it up so that your application "launches" as a pop-up.

Comment: More advanced techniques don't use Swing/Applets/JNLP and resort to JSP/Servlets which is kind of HTML mixed with Java. But in order to do that, you'll have to completely rewrite your existing UI.

Comment: Otay, thank you so much for the clarification @adarshr.  Rewriting the swing sounds like a lot of work, but would a Swing builder help?

Comment: @CodeAdmiral A Swing builder will make the Swing part easier. As it stands, this question is far too broad for SO--I'd suggest getting started then coming back with specific issues.

Comment: Which Swing builder, @CodeAdmiral?

Comment: @gurung While admirable, the appropriateness of an SO question isn't gated on age; the question as it stands is far too broad. We can encourage the OP in other ways, like by pointing him/her to tutorials and resources, and explaining why the question doesn't work while being respectful and age-/experience-appropriate.

Comment: @adarshr That's another question of mine...

Comment: Thank you @DaveNewton, I understand that it is too broad, so I will narrow it down, and start researching the jnlp, java web starts, and applets.

Comment: @CodeAdmiral I'd also recommend coderanch.com as a beginner's site--they also expect posters to do a lot of their own work, but their Q&A is more free-form than SO and targets a different audience, IMO. Good luck; you've got the right mindset.

Comment: Its alright, I understand that the question was too vague, and that I should have narrowed it down before asking it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several way to do this with java.

One way is to do it with Java Servlet.

You need a html form with an action that points to a Servlet (an extended Java Class)
Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaServletExamples.html)

Comment: Gotcha, Thanks a ton and a half.  +1

Comment: The link in your answer is dead :(

Comment: When you try to find another example enter "Java Servlet Example" in yout favorite Search Engine ... :)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of running a server or applet, it is also possible to compile Java into JavaScript using [JSweet](http://www.jsweet.org/).

This is JSweet's translation of your `Permutations` class:

```
 /* Generated from Java with JSweet 2.0.0 - http://www.jsweet.org */
var Permutations = (function () {
    function Permutations() {
    }
    Permutations.factorial = function (num) {
        var factorial = 1;
        for (var forBlockvar = num; forBlockvar > 1; forBlockvar--) {
            factorial = factorial * forBlockvar;
        }
        ;
        return factorial;
    };
    Permutations.main = function (args) {
        var FactNmR;
        var n = 10;
        var num = n;
        var r = 4;
        var nMr = n - r;
        var FactN = Permutations.factorial(num);
        if (nMr <= 1) {
            FactNmR = 1;
        }
        else {
            num = nMr;
            FactNmR = Permutations.factorial(num);
        }
        var permutations = FactN;
        permutations = Math.floor(permutations / FactNmR);
        console.info(permutations);
    };
    return Permutations;
}());
Permutations["__class"] = "Permutations";
Permutations.main(null);
```

Comment: would this work if I have multiple libraries, packages and classes though?